# String manipulation, extract and remove image tags from a string

Tags: c#, string

I have a string which may contain one or more image tags ...

I have written a snippet to filter out the image tags from the string
like

```
        string test = "Hello there <img>Image1</img> How are you ?<img>Image2</img>";
        int imgstartindex = test.IndexOf("<img>");
        int imgendindex = test.IndexOf("</img>");
        List<string> imagetags = new List<string>();

        while(imgstartindex!=-1 && imgendindex!=-1)
        {
            string imagetag = test.Substring(imgstartindex, (imgendindex + 6)-imgstartindex);
            imagetags.Add(imagetag);
             test= test.Replace(imagetag, "");
             imgstartindex = test.IndexOf("<img>");
             imgendindex = test.IndexOf("</img>");
        }
```

Output :

```
 test="Hello there How are you?"
```

imagetags:

```
 "<img>Image1</img>" [0]

 "<img>Image2</img>" [1]
```

Is there a better alternative?

Comment: I assume this is not really html?

Comment: Ehhh, don't change your question substantially after an answer has been given. This sets others readers off. I tried to give an updated answer in a comment.

Comment: Sorry :( Forgot to add the output I need

Comment: And just hope no one will write `<img                      >`

Comment: `test= test.Replace(imagetag, "");` will replace all instances of that image tag. Is that what you want? Or do they all need to be listed separately in the `imagetags` list?

Comment: I need all the instances of the image tag replaced. Also need the image tags in a list.

Answer (score 9):

You can use this regular expression, that does all for you:

```
<img>(.*?)<\/img>
```

It matches an image tag, then a non-greedy match on anything, followed by an image end tag.

Use it like this:

```
string s = Regex.Replace(@"abc<img>def</img>ghi", @"<img>(.*?)<\/img>", "$1");
```

(the first parameter is your input)

Comment: I dont want to lose the image tags, Patrick. I need those too.

Comment: Why didn't you say so? Never mind, you can use [`Regex.Match`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the matches and replace them. You have to do more processing by hand then.

Comment: This works yes, but don't think this is generally a good way to parse tagged data like xml or html: http://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/

Comment: @weston: I agree on you it isn't the best way. It isn't actually HTML, so there might be a problem either way... Parsing it might give issues too, since the other text might not follow HTML rules.

Comment: @weston: I actually first commented to OP he should parse it as HTML... :)